# German language version of the form is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2

I've created a language version for a Form using "Web Form for Marketers" in *Sitecore*. The usual english version is working fine. Now, I've created the German version of the Form and trying to load the page.

It is breaking with Error:

```
"{System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'"
```

and

```
Sitecore.Data.Query.ParseException: End of string expected at position 39.
```

Am I missing something? What are the steps to create a language version for WFFM Form? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Got the reason for the error. There was a hyphen "-" in the path. Removed it and my page started working. "Web Forms for Marketeres" doesn't work with "-".

Thanks,
Chandana